# Host multiple Angular application in IIS

Tags: angular, iis

I want to host multiple angular apps in iis.

localhost:80/App1/heroes

localhost:3000/App2/employees

How to do URL rewrite so that localhost:80/App2 serves from localhost:3000/App2/employees

Comment: You can get some ideas from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.